# Wrong string encoding tomcat java linux

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, servlets, redhat

I developed a web application which takes a client's txt file, read contents of file and write to new created txt file and saves it to local machine, then gives client link to download saved file.  File may contain cyrillic characters. The web application is developed using JSP and Servlet (jdk 6), deployed on Apache Tomcat 7, on Windows 7. It works properly, but when I deployed built WAR file on apache tomcat 7, OS redhat 5.5, jdk 7, when client downloads saved file, the cyrillic letters are shown as rectangles. What may be reason of it? the tomcat configurations are same, difference is on my machine jdk6, windows7 64bit OS and on server jdk7, redhat 32bit OS.

Comment: Can you show us how you create the file on the server?

Comment: define encoding explicitly in your app as you are reading and writing into file.

Comment: `File f = new File("result.txt"); PrintWriter pw = new     PrintWriter(f); InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("input.txt")); String line = is.readLine(); pw.print(line + "\r\n"); pw.flush(); pw.close();`

Comment: Can you also show how you copy the contents of the received file into the newly created file?

Comment: just encode the file using utf-8

Comment: Are you following all steps mentioned in http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding#Q8?